# How to copy "innerText" to clipboard that has multiple texts?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

First I'll show you my code and then explain what I am trying to achieve.

```js
Class SectionHues extends React.Component {
  handleClick = () => {
    console.log(this.input.innerText);
  }
  render() {
    return(
      {Object.entries(this.props.colorChange).map(([colorName, colorHex]) => (
      <div key={shortid.generate()} className="button-hues-container">

        {/** On button click copy the span's innerText */}
        <button onClick={this.handleClick} className="button-hues">
          <span className="hues-info">
            <span className="section-color-name">
             {colorName}
            </span>

             {/** Need to copy the innerText of this span tag */}
             <span ref={input => this.input = input} className="color-hex">
              {colorHex.toLowerCase()}
             </span>
              {/** End copy */}
            </span>
          </button>
        </div>
      ))}
    )
  }
}
```

As you can see the button loops through the database and creates multiple buttons with it's respective text. I have tried to solve the problem using `ref` but I could not. 
On clicking whichever button the text copied is the same. Is there some way to link the button to the `id` so that on clicking the button, it only copies it's respective text?
If you have an alternative approach without using an `id`, that would work too.

Comment: 1) Can you show your `onClick` handler?  2) The `innerText` will always be `colorHex.toLowerCase()`.  Can you use that, or is the code you posted simpler than what you really want to do?

Comment: Edited the question. Yes, the ```innerText``` will be ```colorHex.toLowerCase()```, but the problem is ```innerText``` is not related to it's button.

Comment: you need to pass the text as a parameter to handleClick.`() => handleClick(text)`

Comment: @gaditzkhori can you write an answer, please. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a parameter to `handleClick`.

```
<button onClick={() => this.handleClick(colorHex.toLowerCase())}
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked like a charm. It's embarrassing when the answer is in front of you, but still you cannot see it. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

i have just added this javascript function.i think it will work.

```html
<html>
<head>
<script>
function copyToClipboardfunc() {
  var copyText = document.getElementById("myInput");
  copyText.select();
  document.execCommand("Copy");
  
}
</script>
</head>
<body style="width:500px;margin:80px auto;">
<textarea id="myInput" rows="4" cols="50">
Welcome to lorem ipsum gallery.

</textarea>
</body>
<br>
<button onclick="copyToClipboardfunc()">Copy text</button>

</html>
```

Comment: It's not Reactic